# Why does the footer only stay at the bottom for the first slide of my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a text slideshow for a menu. On the first slide of the slideshow, the footer is fine. For the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 7th slide, the footer goes to the middle of the page. The 6th footer is also fine. The slide is manually controlled by arrows. Please direct me to a thread if this has been answered. This is different than simple "Footer not staying at the bottom". (The footer looks fine on other pages of the website) I'm sorry the code is so long but I had to say all of this to fully show the issue

I've tried using &nbsp under every  slide instead of just having one at the bottom. I've tried adjusting the slideshow maximum width.

```
//SLIDE CSS
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
//FOOTER CSS

footer {

   background: teal;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

}


//HTML CODE
<div class="slideshow-container">
//this one hs normal footer
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 7</div>
 <span class = "left" style = "width: 35%;">
//content
</span>
<span class = "left" style = "width: 30%;">
//content
</span>
<span class = "left" style = "width: 35%;">
//content
</span>
</br>
</br>
</div>


// only showed two slides to shorten code

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

&nbsp;

</div>
// J A V A  S C R I P T
<script language = "javascript">
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script></br>
//F O O T E R  C O D E
<footer style = "line-height: 70px" class = "footer">
<div class = "foot1">
<div class = "foottitle">Restaurant</div>
</div>
<div class = "foot2">
<div class = "ul2">
  <div class = "footsub">VISIT US</div>
  <div class = "li2">Address</div>
  <div class = "li2">Blah blah</div>
  <div class = "li2">city zipcode</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

I want the footer of the page to be at the bottom when I am on all slides

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any positioning like "relevant" and offsets like "bottom" then I think you can do set it by removing positioning on footer and slider as well.
If it does not work then is there any live link for it if it is not live then what styling is applying on main wrapper of slider?

Comment: user this style for slide show container: .slideshow-container {
 max-width: 800px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 min-height: 585px;
}

Comment: this for footer: 
footer {
 background: teal;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 color: white;
 clear: both;
}